# update attribute showing black page magento2

Tags: magento-2.2.1

[image: update attribute showing black page]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to catalog->product.
2. Select 2 or more products.
3. Click Action and select update attributes.

Comment: Have you done any customize?
Might be it is a cause of customize. Disable all the custom module and check.

Comment: i've checked it by disabling the custom modules but its not working!!

Comment: hi @KirtiNariya any suggestion about this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301858/magento-2-how-to-set-customer-group-price-programatically-through-csv