# Magento 2: How to set Customer Group Price Programatically Through CSV

Tags: magento-2.2.1

How to create Customer Group Price programatically using CSV?

Answer (score 0):

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(3);

    foreach ($collection as $product){
        $appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
        $appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

        $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
        $productObj = $productRepository->getById($product->getId());

        $tierPrice[0] = array('website_id' => 0,'cust_group' => 2, 'price_qty' => 1 , 'price' => 100.0 );
        $productObj->setPrice(103.59); //read your csv file price here and loop it as you required
        $productObj->setTierPrice($tierPrice);
        $productObj->save();   
    }
```

Comment: you must elaborate your answer!

Comment: using object manager is not a good coding practice in magento i think.